# Laravel 5.2 Redirect to Page Query String

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, pagination

I'm getting results of products in category page. And i have system to hide sold out products.

Think that there exists ten pages for all products in category. When i check checkbox hide sold out products. The system returns ?page=10 But there is no product in ?page=10

I decided to use redict system.

```
$products = (new Product)->getProductsOfCategory($category->id);
$last_page = $products->lastPage();

if(request()->has('page'))
{
    if(request()->get('page') > $last_page)
    {
        $location = categoryUrl($category->id, $category->category, NULL, NULL, $last_page);
        //Output: http://dtl/en/cat/authentic-purses/120?page=7
        return redirect()->to($location);
    }
}
```

But i'm getting error

**`Method [links] does not exist on Redirect.`**

$products is paginated data.

---

UPDATE :

```
public function getProductsOfCategory($category_id){
    $query = $this->where('category_id', $category_id);
    $query = $this->productFilter($query);

    $query = $this->productSorting($query);
    return $query->paginate(18);
}
```

---

How can i get rid of this error ?

Comment: We're missing code here. Can you dump the output of `$location`? Also - I'd advise looking into why the system is returning a page with no products, rather than hotfixing what happens if a user goes there.

Comment: i updated output of location

Comment: System is returning a page with no products. Because i'm posting to same page. Shows only in stocks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getProductsOfCategory` should return instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`
Then somewhere in your partial view you should use it method `$products->links()` yo view pagination section on website.

This error is you get when you call this method on bad object for example: `redirect()->links()`.

If this won't help You should paste here your partial view.

Comment: When i dd $products->links() i'm getting result. that method is an instance of Paginator

Comment: Ok then show the body of: `getProductsOfCategory` method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without using Laravel Redirect Method.

```
header("Location: ".$location);
die();
```

works fine instead of

```
return redirect()->to($location)
```

Comment: Glad that you solved it! As a sidenote, you could just do `exit(header("Location: " . $location));`. Also, mark your own answer as Solved! :)